# Raspberry pi ethernet cable no longer working

Tags: pi-3b+, ethernet

I was working on Raspberry pi3+ for few days and didnt have any issues today unexpectedly after connecting it the ethernet LEDs didnt light up i tried 2 different ethernet cables the issue persisted and the cables are not faulty i tried connecting with the laptop and it worked fine. After twisting the cable a bit the LED light up for 1-2 secs.
Any ideas what's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps you've damaged the ethernet port itself - look inside - check if it looks OK ... failing that, you may have damaged the connection of the port to the PCB - look for damage

Comment: There are no signs of any kind of damage it was working yesterday and just learned from a colleague that had it earlier that it wasn't also working perfectly with them.

Comment: Can you still get on the Pi? If so, do the logs provide any clue?

Comment: maybe the failure is at the other end of the cable

Comment: `it wasn't also working perfectly with them` - so, it was damaged before you got it